# How to add two textviews to the child of an Expandable Listview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am trying to place two textviews side by side in an expandable Listview. unfortunately all solutions found on stack overflow and Google search turned out to be futile.

This link looks similar but apparently not the solution 
    [adding two textViews to the header of the expandable listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595540/adding-two-textviews-to-the-header-of-the-expandable-listview)

What i want is to place the two texts views to the child not the header of the expandable list.

**Image of how i want the two texts views to look like on the child view** [image: side by side textview format on expandable list]

**ExpandableListAdapter.java**

```
  public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> ParentItem;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> ChildItem;


    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> ParentItem,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> ChildItem) {
        this.context = context;
        this.ParentItem = ParentItem;
        this.ChildItem = ChildItem;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return this.ChildItem.get(this.ParentItem.get(listPosition))
                .get(expandedListPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return expandedListPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String expandedListText = (String) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
        }

        //TextView text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item1);
        TextView text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item2);
        //text1.setText("");
        text2.setText(expandedListText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
        return this.ChildItem.get(this.ParentItem.get(listPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
        return this.ParentItem.get(listPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.ParentItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
        return listPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_item, null);
        }
        TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
        listTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);

        TextView location = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.item1);
        location.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        location.setText("whatever you want");
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return true;
    }


    public static HashMap<String, List<String>> getData() {
        HashMap<String, List<String>> ParentItem = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

        List<String> NADMO = new ArrayList<String>();
        NADMO.add("38838333");
        NADMO.add("03220-34084");
        NADMO.add("03820-23110");
        NADMO.add("03222-22145");
        NADMO.add("03120-46676");
        NADMO.add("03720-23154");
        NADMO.add("03920-22657");
        NADMO.add("020-2006943/03620-27158");
        NADMO.add("03321-32127");
        NADMO.add("03520-27271");

        List<String> GPS = new ArrayList<String>();
        GPS.add("Lion");
        GPS.add("Tiger");
        GPS.add("Leopard");
        GPS.add("Cheetah");
        GPS.add("Bear");

        List<String> TPS = new ArrayList<String>();
        TPS.add("Cricket");
        TPS.add("Football");
        TPS.add("Tennis");
        TPS.add("Basket Ball");
        TPS.add("Base Ball");


        ParentItem.put("NADMO"), NADMO);
        ParentItem.put("GPS", GPS);
        ParentItem.put("TPS", TPS);

        return ParentItem;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class CodeDir extends AppCompatActivity {
ExpandableListView expandableListView;
ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
List<String> expandableListTitle;
HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_code_dir);

    //TOOLBAR SUPPORT - Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
    expandableListDetail = ExpandableListAdapter.getData();
    expandableListTitle = new ArrayList<String>(expandableListDetail.keySet());
    expandableListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, expandableListTitle, expandableListDetail);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
    expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " ListView Open.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " ListView Closed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    expandableListDetail.get(
                            expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(
                            childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            )
                    .show();
            return false;
        }
    });
}

}
```

**child_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:padding="2dp">

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
           android:text="Left Side"
           android:textSize="20sp"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Right side"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: how they are looking right now? add current screen shot too?

Comment: @SohailZahid Yes but on the child of the expandable list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help. Create a relative layout programmatically, add the text views to the relative layout and add the relative layout to the expected view.

Something like this:
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

*parentView*.addView(relativeLayout);